# Two Gaussian distribution plot on the same axis

Tags: matlab, plot, gaussian

I am trying to plot two Gaussian distribution both with mean zero, one with variance 1 and the other with variance 2 on the same axis. Here is my code.

```
X= 0 + 1.*randn(2,500);
plot(X(1,:),X(2,:),'x');
hold on
%plot(m(1),m(2),'r*')
Y= 0 + 2.*randn(2,500);
plot(Y(1,:),Y(2,:),'gx')
```

Please check and see if i have done it correctly. I also want to have them in 2-D plot and superimpose.

Thanks.

Comment: Any idea on this above question please?

Comment: When you write that you want to plot Gaussian distributions, you probably mean the density function? Because that's not what you are computing here. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution to see how the plots should look like.

Comment: That's correct and your code works fine for me

Comment: Yea, i have seen how it should look like. Thanks. My problem is which matlab plot function should i use to achieve that shape?

Comment: Any idea on how it can be plotted in 2-D?

Answer (score 4):

You are plotting the data you have randomly generated (with a normal distribution). If that's what you want, yes, it works ok.

If you want to plot the density functions of the variables, you can do it the following way:

```
mu = 0;
sigma1 = 1;
sigma2=2;
x = -4*sigma2:1e-3:4*sigma2; 
y1 = pdf('normal', x, mu, sigma1);
y2 = pdf('normal', x, mu, sigma2);
plot(x, y1)
hold on 
plot(x, y2, 'r')
legend('mu=0, sigma=1', 'mu=0, sigma=2')
title('Density functions')
```

[image: Plot of the density functions]

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Now i just want to know how one can estimate the mean and covariance of the above X and Y distrisbutions in matlab? How do u also plot the isocontour of the covariance matrix estimated.

Comment: Your X and Y are arrays with a size=2x500. If for example you want to calculate the mean of the first row of X, you can do the following: mean(X(1,:)) and the same for the X. I'm not sure of what else you are trying to do...

Comment: No, now my X and Y are arrays with a size=1x500. I just want to estimate the mean and the covariance of the two distributions. I am plotting both X and Y on the same axes. Now i just want to estimate the parameters(mean and covariance) and superimpose them maybe use hold on. I am also trying to plot the isocontour of the covariance estimated so that i can see how it looks like. I hope now you understand. Thanks.

Comment: Have you searched Matlab help for the fuctions you need? http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/ I think that ´mean´ and ´cov´ will be useful.

Comment: I did calculate the mean and covariance, i just need to know how to plot the isocontour of the estimated covariance so that i can see how it looks like. Any idea on this please?